# Printing array as string returns weird characters on end

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to cut off the first two characters of *argv[] and store them in an array.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char salt[2] = {argv[1][0], argv[1][1]};
    printf("%s\n",salt);
}
```

After compiling, when I run this program at the terminal by typing in ./program_name asdf, I'm expecting that "asdf" is passed in as *argv[]. So I'm expecting the program will print out "as". However, what actually happens is that it will print out "as", followed by same random characters. Here's what came out the last few times:

ash. 
asX 
asKs 
as8\8

Comment: Because strings are null-terminated in C.

Comment: NUL terminator Q #00023523761

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings are essentially null-terminated character sequences in C. In your array there are only two non-null characters, so when you attempt to print it as a string, its end is indeterminate. This results in *undefined behavior*.

If you want to construct a string from a character array, extend the size of the array by one and add a null character at the end:

```
char salt[3] = {argv[1][0], argv[1][1], '\0'};
//        ^ Extend                      ~~~~ Terminate
```

Comment: Nice answer, specially the annotations..

Comment: `char salt[3]` isn't necessary. `char salt[]` is better as size is computed automatically

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Or the explicit terminator is unnecessary if the dimension is given. There are no partial initialisers in C.

Comment: @Olaf you're everywhere :) yes. Either specify size OR nul-terminate.Personally I'd perfer nul-terminate, so someone who comes later to maintain the code and adds another char doesn't trip on the size.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I would refrain from using an array at all. It is hardly less complicated than passing the characters directly to `printf` with `%c`. Anyway, that's soo very basic and specific I don't think it is worth staying here one day longer.

Comment: @Olaf agreed if you only have 2 chars...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: if you have more characters, one better find an algorithm and use a loop. In that case, you have to use a complete type anyway.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
char salt[2] = {argv[1][0], argv[1][1]};
```

you don't leave enough space for a terminating NUL character, so it reads until it finds the next NUL in memory (which is undefined behaviour and, if it doesn't find a NUL, eventually crashes with a SIGSEGV).

You could either do

```
char salt[] = {argv[1][0], argv[1][1], 0};
```

and proceed as you do, or you do

```
printf("%c%c\n", argv[1][0], argv[1][1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking undefined behavior by passing an un-terminated `char` array to the function `printf()` which expects a null terminated array. So, you have to store the `'\0'` character like follows:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char salt[3] = {argv[1][0], argv[1][1], '\0'};
    printf("%s\n",salt);
}
```

Don't forget to increase your array size!